# Can't upload photo to my Trello profile

Tags: trello, avatar

I have tried to upload a photo to my profile in Trello but it will not save completely.

The first time it took only a part of the photo (torso) and not my face.
The second time I tried to upload a photo it just didn't do it.

Comment: How big (width/height and KB) is the photo you're trying to upload?  What's the file format?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a bug. Are you still seeing the issue? Could you email support@trello.com with more details, and include the image you are trying to upload?

I should note that there is a 10mb upload limit.